# Kicked out of Gnome desktop intermitently

Tags: debian, gnome

I am running Debian 8 (Jessie) using the default Gnome desktop and installation.

Sometimes I will be logged off Gnome and brought back to the graphical login screen where I must enter my password. When I log back, all programs will have been closed and I am brought back to a fresh desktop. This is happening at irregular intervals.

How can I diagnose this problem?

Is there a file that would contain information to help me find the source of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - I don't know fix your problem, but I would try log on tty1 with same user, and see if it logout too. If it logout you know it is not a problem with X, gnome...

2 - Some days ago I had a strange problem with X window, the programs crash and i couldn't logon again with normal user. I saw the logs in /var/log to find something, but I haven't found anything. The problem with me is /var/log too large (I guess, i couldn't fix my own problem!).

3 - Anyway the files in /var/log/ may help.